# Segmentation fault in CS50 Speller. Why?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, hashtable, cs50

I am working on the CS50 pset5 Speller, and I keep getting a segmentation fault error. Debug50 suggests the problem is the line `n->next = table[index];` in the implementation of the `load` function, line 110. I tried to revise but I can´t figure out why it would give error. Here below my code, can anyone please help me?

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 150000;

// Nodes counter
int nodes_counter = 0;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int hash_value = hash(word);
    node *cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (cursor != NULL)
    {
        cursor = table[hash_value];
    }

    if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0) // If word is first item in linked list
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else // Iterate over the list by moving the cursor
    {
        while (cursor->next != NULL)
        {
            if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0) // If word is found
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cursor = cursor->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // Adaptation of FNV function, source https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/fnv-hash/c/
    const unsigned int fnv_prime = 0x811C9DC5;
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        hash *= fnv_prime;
        hash ^= (*word);
    }

    return hash;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open Dictionary File (argv[1] or dictionary?)
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Read until end of file word by word (store word to read in word = (part of node)?)

    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // For each word, create a new node
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(n->word, word);
            //Omitted to avoid segmentation fault n->next = NULL;
            nodes_counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            return 2;
        }

        // Call hash function (input: word --> output: int)
        int index = hash(word);

        // Insert Node into Hash Table
        n->next = table[index];
        table[index] = n;
    }
    return false;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // Return number of nodes created in Load
    if (nodes_counter > 0)
    {
        return nodes_counter;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor->next != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` is great at debugging these.

Comment: In the `check` function `node *cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));` followed by `cursor = table[hash_value];` is a memory leak. If `table[hash_value]` is NULL then all the rest of the code in the function is using a NULL pointer. You shouldn't need to allocate anything inside that function. Grab the entry from the table and if it isn't NULL check if you found the word, otherwise return false.

Comment: There's also no guarantee that the `hash` function will return a value that is under 150000 so you'd be accessing the array out of bounds. You need something like `int hash_value = hash(word) % N ;` to force it isn't the correct range. You need to do this anywhere you use the return value from the `hash` function.

Comment: In your `hash` function, although you loop with `i` for the length of `word`, you don't actually use `i` to index into `word`, so you just use the first character of `word` over and over. Instead of `hash ^= (*word);`, I think you want `hash ^= word[i];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `node *table[N];` cannot be only be defined as a global object if `N` is a constant expression. `N` is defined as a `const unsigned int`, but `N` is not a constant expression in C (albeit it is in C++). Your program compiles only because the compiler accepts this as a non portable extension. Either use a macro or an enum.
- you overwrite `cursor` as soon as it is allocated in `check()`. There is no need to allocate a node in this function.
- the `hash()` function should produce the same hash for words that differ only in case.
- the `hash()` function only uses the first letter in `word`.
- the `hash()` function can return a hash value >= `N`.
- `fscanf(file, "%s", word)` should be protected agains buffer overflow.
- you do not check if `cursor` is non null before dereferencing it in `unload()`

Here is a modified version:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
enum { N = 150000 };

// Nodes counter
int nodes_counter = 0;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word) {
    int hash_value = hash(word);

    // Iterate over the list by moving the cursor
    for (node *cursor = table[hash_value]; cursor; cursor = cursor->next) {
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0) {
            // If word is found
            return true;
        }
    }
    // If word is not found
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word) {
    // Adaptation of FNV function, source https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/fnv-hash/c/
    unsigned int fnv_prime = 0x811C9DC5;
    unsigned int hash = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        hash *= fnv_prime;
        hash ^= toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);
    }
    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else a negative error number
int load(const char *dictionary) {
    // Open Dictionary File (argv[1] or dictionary?)
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Read until end of file word by word (store word to read in word = (part of node)?)

    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    char format[10];
    // construct the conversion specifier to limit the word size
    //    read by fscanf()
    snprintf(format, sizeof format, "%%%ds", LENGTH);

    while (fscanf(file, format, word) == 1) {
        // For each word, create a new node
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL) {
            fclose(file);
            return -2;
        }
        strcpy(n->word, word);
        n->next = NULL;
        nodes_counter++;

        // Call hash function (input: word --> output: int)
        int index = hash(word);

        // Insert Node into Hash Table
        n->next = table[index];
        table[index] = n;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void) {
    // Return number of nodes created in Load
    return nodes_counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        table[i] = NULL;
        while (cursor != NULL) {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wow, it seems I had quite few errors. I checked and went through all your bullet points, it is great that someone takes the time to check and explain the mistakes. Thank you a lot for this, it made me learn quite few things.